# Keyed each block VS Reactive declaration (Svelte)

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm following the Svelte tutorial at https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/keyed-each-blocks and there is this example for keyed each blocks :

App.svelte :

```
<script>
    import Thing from './Thing.svelte';

    let things = [
        { id: 1, name: 'apple' },
        { id: 2, name: 'banana' },
        { id: 3, name: 'carrot' },
        { id: 4, name: 'doughnut' },
        { id: 5, name: 'egg' }
    ];

    function handleClick() {
        things = things.slice(1);
    }
</script>

<button on:click={handleClick}>
    Remove first thing
</button>

{#each things as thing (thind.id)}
    <Thing name={thing.name} />
{/each}
```

Thing.svelte :

```
<script>
    const emojis = {
        apple: '',
        banana: '',
        carrot: '',
        doughnut: '',
        egg: ''
    };

    // the name is updated whenever the prop value changes...
    export let name;

    // ...but the "emoji" variable is fixed upon initialisation
    // of the component because it uses `const` instead of `$:`
    const emoji = emojis[name];
</script>

<p>{emoji} = {name}</p>
```

The purpose of this page is to use the keyed each block `{#each things as thing (thind.id)} ... {/each}`. But I don't understand what is the purpose of doing this, as there is a really simple solution with using a reactive declaration : `$: emoji = emojis[name];` instead of `const emoji = emojis[name];`. My questions are :

Is using a keyed each block useful only to have `const` variables ?

Or it can also be a solution when, let's say we have a lot of variables and we dont want to declare them in a reactive way.

What's the best solution to use ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use a keyed `#each` if you can.

- There are cases where you cannot just update the local state in any logical way to account for changes. It also just takes more work to write components so they update correctly if certain inputs change.
- If there are many items or many updates in a short amount of time, this can cause lag and is just a waste of resources in general. (Also consider mobile devices which are less powerful.)
- It can mess with interactions, e.g. if a certain element is focused but logically that element is now somewhere else (i.e. contents have moved) you now have focus on the wrong element. If focus was somewhere on the last element and an element before that was removed, you lose focus entirely.